# Do these sentences have the same meaning? "to" vs "into"

Tags: prepositions

> Aleydis led me to stairs that descended to the water
>
> Aleydis led me to stairs that descended into the water

Comment: No. If you take the 2nd set of stairs, you're going to get wet.

Comment: "to the water" means that the steps end where the water starts.  "into the water" means that the stairs continue down from the end of the dry steps.  As @Dan Bron said above.

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be any good reason to capitalize Stairs in the second sentence.   Unless, oh I don't know, Stairs is the title of a book that is about to get wet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No. If you take the 2nd set of stairs, you're going to get wet. – Dan Bron
>
> "to the water" means that the steps end where the water starts. "into the water" means that the stairs continue down from the end of the dry steps. As @Dan Bron said above. – ewormuth